# How I can change the object properties after I add it in the scene and move it?

Tags: modeling, objects

Suppose I add torus in my scene, and I change in **the Minor segments** from 16 to 3. In addition, I made many actions such as scaling, rotating and moving the object. How I can **return** to the Minor segments to 16 after all these actions? I do not add any actions in the edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**:

You can't.

**Long answer**:

Blender doesn't create parametric objects out of the box. Once a mesh has been modified after initial creation (including translate, rotate, or scale) you cannot modify it further with the original tool creation parameters. Blender no longer considers the object a "torus", but it becomes a bunch of vertices, edges and faces instead, like any other mesh.

In the case of a torus you could use a curve to describe the basic profile and then use that as a bevel object on a circle curve.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9CXeprYW1M

There is an addon to create parametric objects https://www.blendernation.com/2019/12/04/blender-2-8x-add-on-review-parametric-objects-wmesh-free/ you might want to try it.